# ACF update_field() inserts the values, but are inaccessible by get_field()

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm getting objects from a 3rd party API and creating a post for each one of them.

Two post types are created `object` and `aruodas-object` (the 3rd party API object type). There is a field group `object` with all the custom fields for the `object` and a field group `aruodas` for some additional custom values for the 3rd party objects.

I have this code in my functions.php

```php
$ad = array('post_type' => 'aruodas-object', 'post_status' => 'publish');
switch($ads[0]['objTypeId']){
    case '1':
        $ad['post_id'] = $ads[0]['Id'];
        $ad['post_title'] = $ads[0]['addressLong'];
        $ad['post_excerpt'] = $ads[0]['addressLong'];
        $ad['post_date'] = $ads[0]['AddExpDate'];
        $ad['post_date_gmt'] = get_gmt_from_date($ads[0]['AddExpDate']);
        $ad['post_author'] = get_users(array('nicename' => substr($ads[0]['notes'], -6), 'fields' => 'ID'))[0];

        //Custom
        $ad['object_parduotas'] = $ads[0]['Sold'];
        $ad['object_tipas'] = 'butas';
        $ad['object_veiksmas'] = 'Pardavimui';
        ...
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

$existing_post = get_page_by_title($ad['post_title'], OBJECT, 'aruodas-object');

if (null === $existing_post) {
    $id = wp_insert_post($ad);

    foreach($ad as $key => $value){
        if(str_starts_with($key, 'object_')){
            update_field($key, $value, $id);
        }
    }

    //3rd party only fields from different group

    update_field('nuotraukos', array_map(function($url){return ['url' => $url];}, $ad['nuotraukos']), $id);
    update_field('thumbnail', $ad['thumbnail'], $id);
}
```

The post is successfully created and values inserted, but in `page-objektai.php` the `get_field()` returns `null` until I go to the newly created post and update it, then it works as expected.

```php
<?php while ( $result->have_posts() ) : $result->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $objectData = get_field('object');
        // if(!$objectData) return;
        switch($objectData['objekto_tipas']){
        ...
        ?>
        //HTML card
?>
```

I thought it might be a problem with the cache, but any of the solutions I found didn't help, also using field values for the key in `update_field()` doesn't even insert the values in the field when the post is created.

Comment: Sometimes, especially when inserting a new post instead of updating an existing one, you need to use the field key instead of the name: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/#updating-via-field-key

Comment: In your page-objektai.php what values are returned from `print_r( get_fields() )`  also, for whatever it's worth... `get_page_by_title()` is deprecated.  https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/03/06/get_page_by_title-deprecated/

Comment: About the keys: as I said tried to do so but to no avail, will try again, maybe I missed something

Comment: `print_r(get_fields('object'));` returns nothing, while `var_dump(get_field('object');` returns NULL. Also, will change the `get_page_by_title()` with `WP_Query`, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

First of all, to save a new post use `field_key` in the `update_field()`.

In my case, I had field group `object` and in it a group field `object` which acts as a repeater field. To access it I always use `object_{field_name}`, but for insertion, you can't just specify the key for each field in the group field, you have to pass an array of `field_key => value`.

I changed the $ad array to

```php
$ad['field_6591851000d4a'] = $ads[0]['Sold']; //object_parduotas
$ad['field_646b96f1d26d7'] = 'butas'; //object_tipas
$ad['field_646b9784d26d8'] = 'Pardavimui'; //object_veiksmas
$ad['field_6533fa8370c23'] = getCity($ads[0]['city']); //object_savivaldybė
$ad['field_657ea8601a3ae'] = getCity($ads[0]['city']); //object_miestas
...
```

And the insertion loop was changed to this:

```php
$id = wp_insert_post($ad);

$fields = array();
foreach($ad as $key => $value){
    if(str_starts_with($key, 'field_')){
        $fields[$key] = $value;
        // update_field($key, $value, $id);
    }
}
//print_r($fields);
update_field('object', $fields, $id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you can try.........

```
$objectData = get_field('object', get_the_ID());
```

It might be fix your issue